# Regex matching HTML option tags which are unselected and also selected

Tags: regex

Can some recommend a regex to return the value when an item is selected as well as unselected as seen below.

```
<option value="32_1002_ACCT1001" selected="selected">ACCT1001 -- Accounting 1a</option>
<option value="32_1002_ACCT1002">ACCT1002 -- Accounting 1b</option>
```

My regex currently works only for the unselected option seen below.

```
(<option value="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/option>)
```

EDIT:

Thanks for the great responses guys, however I should have been a bit more detailed and specific.

I am using it in a [screen-scraper](http://www.screen-scraper.com/) extractor pattern as follows:

```
<option value="~@COURSE_ID@~">~@COURSE_CODE@~ -- ~@COURSE_NAME@~</option>
```

where ~@COURSE_ID@~ specifies the following regex query:

```
([^"]+)
```

Works fine for all option tags EXCEPT the first one which is already selected.

I am testing out your suggestions at the moment, but if anyone wants to jump in with a sure fire solution that would be great.

I'm really struggling with this one, nothing seems to be working!

Comment: What language are you using? Also, [did you check the FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/faq)?

Comment: Hi Kobi, I am using an application called screen-scraper as mentioned in the question edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Kobi but if you really want to use regex here is a solution in perl :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    print $_;
    if (/^(<option value="([^"]+).*?(?:selected="selected")?.*)$/) {
        print "match\t value=$2\n";
    } else {
        print "NOT match\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
<option value="32_1002_ACCT1001" selected="selected">ACCT1001 -- Accounting 1a</option>
<option value="32_1002_ACCT1002">ACCT1002 -- Accounting 1b</option>
```

output :

```
<option value="32_1002_ACCT1001" selected="selected">ACCT1001 -- Accounting 1a</option>
match    value=32_1002_ACCT1001
<option value="32_1002_ACCT1002">ACCT1002 -- Accounting 1b</option>
match    value=32_1002_ACCT1002
```

Comment: First, thanks. It is my understanding that the OP wants to capture all `<option>` tags from an HTML file, and get their values. The `selected` attribute gets in the way of the posted regex. Your solution is pretty close though, it looks better than Gopi's, who removed the relevant capturing group...

Comment: Kobi is right, it is just the selected attribute that gets in the way. I couldn't get M42's regex query to work in http://regexpal.com/ either.

Comment: @reckoner: Sorry, i misunderstood you needs. I've modified the regex to match all options with or without `selected`. You will find the whole line in `$1` and the value in `$2`.

Comment: Thanks M42, works great. screen-scraper uses PERL compatible regex too.

Answer (score 6):

First, its bad idea to use regex for parsing HTML. Use some html parser. (I am tired of writing this, but I just put it as a first sentence as people tend to downvote immediately without this statement :) )

Anyways, just modify your regex to account for all attributes like this

```
(<option[^>]*?>([^<]+)<\/option>)
```

Well, I dont say its an optimal one, its just with minimal modifications to yours

Comment: Testing this in regexpal (http://regexpal.com/) doesn't match the unselected item.

Comment: I'm using regex to parse HTML because I am using screen-scraper (I have edited question, should have mentioned it earlier!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative way to load these values in C# using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://jsbin.com/unasu/");
HtmlNodeCollection options = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//option[@value]");
IEnumerable<string> values = options.Select(o => o.Attributes["value"].Value);
```

Loading a local file, for completeness, is done using:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\file.html");
```

As clearly seen, this solution is a lot more robust than a regex - it won't fail with most code, doesn't care about attributes order, quote formats (single double or none), and many, many more common cases.

Comment: Apologies Kobi, should have mentioned earlier that I am using screen-scraper so I am limited to a single regex string - see edited question.